# Adding a label to a scroll view

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview

I am trying to add a label to a scroll view, then set the contentSize of the scrollview to match the desired size of the label. The problem is I seem to have to make the contentSize bigger than the size of the label:

```
theScrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
bodyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 50.0)];
bodyLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bodyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
bodyLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
bodyLabel.text = event.description; <- basically some long ass text here
bodyLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
bodyLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

here I think Im getting the necessary label size to contain the text

```
CGSize size = [event.description sizeWithFont:bodyLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(bodyLabel.frame.size.width, 9500) lineBreakMode:bodyLabel.lineBreakMode];

frame = bodyLabel.frame; // to get the width
frame.size.height = size.height;    
bodyLabel.frame = frame;
```

here I set the contentSize to the label's Size, but it isn't big enough, I need to 
set it to bodyLabel.frame.size.height + 80 for it to be covered in the scrolling.

```
theScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bodyLabel.frame.size.width, bodyLabel.frame.size.height);
[theScrollview addSubview:bodyLabel];
```

Thanks for any thoughts in advance!

Comment: You should use sizeThatFits on that label instead of using sizeWithFont on the string.

Comment: I see, could you give me an example? I just attempted it and got the same result. Thanks -Uba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[theScrollview addSubView: bodyLabel];
```

Comment: @UbaDuba So are you not seeing the Scrollview? I think it might be because of the line where you are defining your objects...you set the height and width to zero for both, when you said CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 50.0)];

Comment: @UbaDuba in CGRectMake the first two values are for the height and width of the element and the second two values are where the element will display on the screen

Comment: No, I see the scrollview, it just doesn't scroll the entire height of the label (unless I set the contentSize property to 80 more than the height returned from the "sizeWithFont" call.

Comment: according to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html it looks like the first 2 arguments are the x,y coordinates and the last two are the width and height.

Comment: @UbaDuba Could you take a screenshot (Shift+Command+3) and post it please?

Comment: @UbaDuba You are right I got it backwards. In Xcode 4 it automatically suggests it